# How do I use VBA to Duplicate an Entire Section in MS Word and Paste it to an Added Section

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a specified Word Table in my Word document. I want to add a new Section immediately after the Section that contains the source Table, then paste the entire contents of the source Section into the newly added section.

Below is my attempt to code this, but I am open to completely different code that achieves the objective.

My attempt was a function that took the Table as an argument and returns the newly added section. This code worked on the first call, but on the following call it failed to paste with a Run-Time error.

```
Function CopySection(wdSourceTable As Word.Table) As Word.Section
    'Create a new Section after the input Section
 Dim lNdxSource As Long
 Dim wdRange As Word.Range
 Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
 Dim wdSourceSection As Word.Section, wdSection As Word.Section
         
 Set wdDoc = wdSourceTable.Parent
 Set wdRange = wdSourceTable.Range
 
 '--get section object that contains source table
 For Each wdSection In wdDoc.Sections
   If wdRange.Start >= wdSection.Range.Start And wdRange.End <= wdSection.Range.End Then
      Set wdSourceSection = wdSection
   End If
 Next wdSection
 
 If Not wdSourceSection Is Nothing Then
   lNdxSource = wdSourceSection.Index
  
   '--Add a new section after the source section
   wdDoc.Sections.Add (wdDoc.Sections(lNdxSource + 1))
        
   '--Copy the contents of the source section to the new section
   wdSourceSection.Range.copy
   
   ' on second call of this function, throws Run-time error '4198' Command failed
   wdDoc.Sections(lNdxSource + 1).Range.Paste
    End If

ExitProc:
   Set CopySection = wdDoc.Sections(lNdxSource + 1)
End Function
```

I'm running the code from Excel with early binding to the Word library.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use the clipboard. You can use the `FormattedText` property instead. Also, as the `Sections.Add` method returns a `Section` object you don't need to use the index to get the new section.

```
Function CopySection(wdSourceTable As Word.Table) As Word.Section
    'Create a new Section after the input Section
    Dim lNdxSource As Long
    Dim wdRange As Word.Range
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdSourceSection As Word.Section, wdSection As Word.Section, wdNewSection As Section
         
    Set wdDoc = wdSourceTable.Parent
    Set wdRange = wdSourceTable.Range
 
    '--get section object that contains source table
    For Each wdSection In wdDoc.Sections
        If wdRange.Start >= wdSection.Range.Start And wdRange.End <= wdSection.Range.End Then
            Set wdSourceSection = wdSection
        End If
    Next wdSection
 
    If Not wdSourceSection Is Nothing Then
        lNdxSource = wdSourceSection.Index
  
        '--Add a new section after the source section
        Set wdNewSection = wdDoc.Sections.Add(wdDoc.Sections(lNdxSource + 1).Range)
        '--Copy the content to the new section
        wdNewSection.Range.FormattedText = wdSourceSection.Range.FormattedText
    End If

ExitProc:
    Set CopySection = wdNewSection
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @Timothy Rylatt. I used the Section.Index property because for some reason, after the Sections.Add line is executed, the new section is correctly added right after wdSourceSection; however the wdNewSection references the section after the new section. I've traced this using a debug watch. wdSourceSection.Index = 11 and after the sections.add  wdNewSection.Index=13.